# Android-Studio 0.2.2 error update

Tags: android-studio

I use Android-Studio and I try to update it using interface.
I got this error after restart IDE:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry crc-32 (expected 0x536c771d but got 0x0)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:275)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:343)
at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:238)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:360)
at com.intellij.updater.ZipOutputWrapper.close(ZipOutputWrapper.java:140)
at com.intellij.updater.UpdateZipAction.doApply(UpdateZipAction.java:188)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:138)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch$3.forEach(Patch.java:195)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:243)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:191)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:82)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:73)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstall(Runner.java:192)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.access$000(Runner.java:13)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner$1.execute(Runner.java:159)
at com.intellij.updater.SwingUpdaterUI$5.run(SwingUpdaterUI.java:186)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

What is the problem ? How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a long standing bug with IntelliJ (the basis for AndroidStudio). Have a look at their bugtracker for more informations.

I just filed a [new bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117059) about this because thus far it is unresolved and the cause is still rather mysterious. If you want to add anything to it or vote for it or simply watch what is happening...

Comment: I also think is a bug . Thank you for your answer.